# How do you figure out resistor values for a multitap voltage divider?

Tags: voltage-divider

Given a voltage divider as pictured, how would you go about figuring out sensible resistor values R1-R4 that would produce desired voltages V1-V3?

Obviously observing the constraints that V1-V3 < 10V, and V1 > V2 > V3.

[image]

Comment: It depends what the voltages must be, what precision you want, and if there is any specific output impedance requirements. If there are no requirements, you can just put any arbitrary resistance values that produces those voltages.

Comment: Unless this is just an academic exercise, consider that once you connect almost "anything" useful to the load points, the resistance ratios effectively change and all your careful voltage setting goes out the window.   This isn't a practical circuit for the most part.

Answer (score 3):

Under the assumption that all loads are high impedance (which is a common assumption for voltage dividers that drive things like op amp/comparator/ADC inputs, MOSFET gates for cascode FETs that don't need to handle high-frequency signals, etc). If this assumption does not hold, you will need to resort to a full nodal analysis technique or a different simplification that includes the impedance on each node, and you won't have such neat equations. In that case you'll need to take into account the effects of each load's impedance on itself, *and* on all of the other loads -- or just add some op amp buffers.

Start by selecting a total resistance \$R_0\$ (perhaps arbitrarily, perhaps based on the current that the supply ought to source). The assumption above holds as long as \$R_0 \ll R_{L1}, R_0 \ll R_{L2}, ...\$ where the \$R_{L?}\$ values are the load impedances on the corresponding taps of the voltage divider.

Then:

\$R_4\$ is \$R_0 \cdot \frac{V_3-0\,[\text{V}]}{10\,[\text{V}]}\$
\$R_3\$ is \$R_0 \cdot \frac{V_2-V_3}{10\,[\text{V}]}\$
\$R_2\$ is \$R_0 \cdot \frac{V_1-V_2}{10\,[\text{V}]}\$
\$R_1\$ is \$R_0 \cdot \frac{10\,[\text{V}]-V_1}{10\,[\text{V}]}\$

Note that the sum of the four resistances matches \$R_0\$ as we set out to design.

If you prefer a visual model, consider a number line stretching from 0 to 10 representing the total voltage drop across the divider, with the individual voltage drops weighted based on the relative resistances in the divider.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help. I think I've seen this before, but I was having trouble finding it our working it out on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume for the moment no significant loading on the resistor taps.

We know that the current for the divider is:

- I = Vin / (R1+R2+R3+R4)

Using that current, we get for each voltage tap:

- V1 = (R2+R3+R4) * I = (R2+R3+R4) * Vin / (R1+R2+R3+R4)
- V2 = (R3+R4) * I = (R3+R4) * Vin / (R1+R2+R3+R4)
- V3 = R4 * I = R4 * Vin / (R1+R2+R3+R4)

As a practical matter you'd settle on some acceptable current and thus select the total resistance, then partition each IR drop accordingly working from the bottom up.